# Error while importing scopus data in bibliometrix

Tags: r, scopus

I have a list of 4023 elements that I exported from SCOPUS in the .CSV format. This list can be downloaded at the following address:

[link to download data](http://dl.free.fr/rdVzQxpa5)

When I try to import this dataset in in bibliometrix (with biblioshiny interface) i get the following message:
Error 'to' must be a finite number.

Any idea where this error could come from?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let me share you the answer of the author of the app : biblioshiny does not support .csv. It has to be done through bibtex format.